RabbitMQ installer indicates my Erlang is too old
I am trying to install RabbitMQ on a brand new VM Windows server 2019. I first successfully installed Erlang 23.2 and then attempted to Install RabbitMQ 3.8.14. However RabbitMQ installer returns with following message:
your installed version of erlang (7.1) is too old.
I checked the Erlang version through command line:
erl -eval "erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt()."  -noshell and it returns 23.
I cant find any other version of erlang installed on this VM so I am at loss of what is happening here. Thanks
